# Custom jQuery form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I wrote a basic validation check as the bulk of it is done server side but i'm using (snippet not all code):

```
e.preventDefault();

        var error = false;
        var name = $("input[name='name']").val();
        var email = $("input[name='email']").val();

        if(name.length == 0){
        var error = true;
        var name = $("input[name='name']").addClass("error");
        }else{
        $("input[name='name']").removeClass("error");
        }

        if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){
        var error = true;
        var email = $("input[name='email']").addClass("error");
        }else{
        $("input[name='email']").removeClass("error");
        }
```

however if i leave both fields blank only the email field will get the class attached - not only that but aslong as an email is present the form submits - why is the name field being left blank not being picked up?

Comment: For starters, `== '-1'` should be `!== -1` - test against the numeric -1, not the string.

Comment: Also, there is no need to redeclare variables in your if/else conditionals. If you want to update the value of `error`, use `error = true` instead of `var error = true`. If you want to add class, using `$("input[name='name']").addClass("error")` is sufficient, you don't have to store the jQuery object in a variable.

Comment: appreciate the pointers but neither solve the issue posted?

Answer (score 0):

I would do another condition **after the email** one.
Something like :

```
if (email.length == 0 && name.length == 0) {
    $("input[name='email']").addClass("error");
    $("input[name='name']").addClass("error");
}
```